# GenericADOException was unhandeled using Nhibernate CreateSQLQuery() method

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

whats wrong with the following code?

```
public IList<T> GetPostsByUser(object UserId)
    {
        using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var queryString = string.Format("SELECT C FROM {0} AS C WHERE UserId=:UserId", typeof(T));
                return session.CreateSQLQuery(queryString).SetParameter("UserId", UserId).List<T>();
                //return session.QueryOver<T>().List<T>().IsLike(UserId).List();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: **UserId** is casted to object but its origin comes from **System.GUID**

Exception:

> could not execute query
>   [ SELECT C FROM FNHRepository.Entites.Post AS C WHERE UserId=@p0 ]
>     Name:UserId - Value:3010cd36-539c-4b32-a0fb-976bca58ad38
>   [SQL: SELECT C FROM FNHRepository.Entites.Post AS C WHERE UserId=@p0]

Comment: Value of `@p0` should be enclosed in single quotes, like this: `'3010cd36-539c-4b32-a0fb-976bca58ad38'`. It will be added correctly if you are using `.SetGuid()` method instead of `.SetParameter()`. Not sure why you insist on having an object parameter, if you know that `UserId` will always be `Guid`.

Comment: yes, I suggest you must write this comments as answer.

Comment: Baz1nga already provided a similar answer. You can accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note I am explicitly saying the parameter will be of type String this will make sure that Nhibernate wraps the string in single quotes (`''`) which is what the query expects. If you want to use SetParameter then your query needs to have the single quotes set i.e your query should be

```
string.Format("SELECT C FROM {0} AS C WHERE UserId=':UserId'", typeof(T));
```

thus Use this:

```
var queryString = string.Format("SELECT C FROM {0} AS C WHERE UserId=:UserId", typeof(T)); // you can use SetGuid too, which will again wrap it with quotes
return session.CreateSQLQuery(queryString).SetString("UserId", UserId).List<T>();
```

or

```
var queryString = string.Format("SELECT C FROM {0} AS C WHERE UserId=':UserId'", typeof(T));
return session.CreateSQLQuery(queryString).SetParameter("UserId", UserId).List<T>();
```

Also I would suggest you use `typeof(T).Name` instead of using the fully qualified name.

Comment: using string as paramter is not working. Please see the following error.
`Parameter UserId does not exist as a named parameter in [FROM FNHRepository.Entites.Property C WHERE UserId=':UserId']`, Miroslav Popovic's answer was ultimate.